# Convert List of objects to json array to rest template

Tags: java, json, spring-rest

I have to pass `resttemplate` to below `JSON` request.

```
"actions": [
  {
    "path": "/xyz/mno",
    "operation": "Delete"
  },
  {
    "path": "/xyz/abc",
    "operation": "Delete"
  }
]
```

I have `List<WebDlpPoliciesOperationsRequest>` object to convert above JSON. below is my object

```
@AutoValue
@JsonDeserialize(builder = AutoValue_WebDlpPoliciesOperationsRequest.Builder.class)
public abstract class WebDlpPoliciesOperationsRequest {
      @JsonProperty(value="path")
      public abstract String getPath();
    
      @JsonProperty(value = "operation")
      public abstract String getOperation();
    
      @AutoValue.Builder
      public interface Builder {
    
          @JsonProperty(value="path")
          WebDlpPoliciesOperationsRequest.Builder setPath(String path);
    
          @JsonProperty(value="operation")
          WebDlpPoliciesOperationsRequest.Builder setOperation(String operation);
    
          WebDlpPoliciesOperationsRequest build();
      }    
      public static WebDlpPoliciesOperationsRequest.Builder builder() {
            return new AutoValue_WebDlpPoliciesOperationsRequest.Builder();
       }
}
```